# Write unit tests using xUnit and NUnit. VisualStudio code coverage issues

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

```
[Fact]
public void ThrowExceptionTest()
{
    Assert.ThrowsAny<ArgumentException>(() => ThrowException(-1)/*Not covered*/);
}

public void ThrowException(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException();
/*Not covered*/}
```

Why is there a block that is not covered, because throwing an exception leads to execution interruption, which is caused by no execution later?
How can this test ensure coverage?

[image]

---

---

##### Separation line

---

---

Can I understand in this way?

`ToSex()` is my normal project content. In `ToSexTest()`, I tested different branches

```
Assert.ThrowsAny<ArgumentException>(() =>
{
    ToSex(3);
});//The call here threw an exception, so that this line cannot be overwritten
//But it doesn't matter.Because this is the code for unit testing
```

### [image]

Comment: You need a second test that calls `ThrowException()` with a positive `i`. `throw` leaves the method immediately.

Comment: What language are you using? That doesn't look like valid C code.

Comment: I'm a beginner.Can I understand in this way? `Throwexception()` is my normal project content. I called this method twice to test different branches, which solves the problem that the next line under `throw` is not overwritten, and the parameter `action` of `assert.throwsany` is the test project. It is irrelevant that the call triggers an exception and cannot be overwritten